# How to make paginations buttons (Next, Previous) that load button values from database?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I want to make a category `JPanel` in which I get all buttons values from the database on scroll pane but I want to remove the scroll pane and use pagination two buttons (Next, Previous) that control button values from database next or previous.

[Output Image.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juCyp.jpg)

> Image 2 Frome JAva Floreant POS Like this.

[Image#02 JAVA Floreant POS.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1sV3.jpg)

Following my code:

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package posresturent;

import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;
import static java.awt.Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

/**
 *
 * @author ultronhouse11
 */
public class mainPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    /**
     * Creates new form mainPanel
     */
    private JButton btnCategory;
    final int col = 5;
    final int rows = 2;
    Connection con;
    PreparedStatement pst;
    ResultSet rs;

    public mainPanel() {
        initComponents();

        cat_buttons();



    }



    public void cat_buttons() {

        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shopingmoll", "root", "qwer9900");
            String sl = "SELECT * FROM `item_types` ";
            pst = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sl);

            rs = pst.executeQuery();

        //     JFlowPanel jPeople = new JFlowPanel();



             //rs.absolute(5);
            // while (rs.next()) {

                rs.absolute(1);
                rs.absolute(5);

                String a1 = rs.getString("name");
                String a2 = rs.getString("id");
                JButton btn = new JButton();


                btn.setText("<html><body> <h3>" + a1 + "</h3><br> <b></body></html> ");
                btn.setVerticalAlignment((int) CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
                btn.applyComponentOrientation(getComponentOrientation());
                btn.setFocusPainted(false);
                btn.setFocusable(false);
                btn.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);
                btn.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(110, 90));
                btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(90, 80));
                btn.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(110, 90));

                btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        System.out.println(a1+":"+a2);
                    }
                });

                //String a2 = rs.getString(2);
                ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("src/posresturent/cat.jpg");
                // btn.setIcon(img);

                btn.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                btn.setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
                btn.setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.BOTTOM);
                cat_panel.add(btn,"center");

                repaint();
                revalidate();
             //}


             // cat_sch.getViewport().setView(jPeople);

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }



    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jTabbedPane1 = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        sch = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jPanel9 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel11 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        textFieldRectBackground1 = new org.edisoncor.gui.textField.TextFieldRectBackground();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel10 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton6 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton7 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton8 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton9 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton10 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        cat_panel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel5 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButton14 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton15 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jPanel6 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButton22 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton23 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton24 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton25 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton26 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton27 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton11 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton12 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton13 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        sch.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Items", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.CENTER, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION));

        jPanel11.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(1, 0));

        textFieldRectBackground1.setDescripcion("Enter Barcode ...");
        textFieldRectBackground1.setFocusCycleRoot(true);
        jPanel11.add(textFieldRectBackground1);

        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "#SrNo", "Product", "Unit", "Rate"
            }
        ));
        jTable1.setRowHeight(35);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("Total ");

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("Tax");

        jTextField1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jTextField1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.RIGHT);
        jTextField1.setText("0.00");

        jTextField2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jTextField2.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.RIGHT);
        jTextField2.setText("0.00");

        jTextField3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 1, 45)); // NOI18N
        jTextField3.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 51));
        jTextField3.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.CENTER);
        jTextField3.setText(" Rs  0.00");

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setText("<html> Grand <br><br> Total");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel9Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel9);
        jPanel9.setLayout(jPanel9Layout);
        jPanel9Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel9Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel11, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(jPanel9Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel9Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(35, 35, 35)
                .addGroup(jPanel9Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 230, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING))
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 309, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        );
        jPanel9Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel9Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel9Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel11, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 33, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(1, 1, 1)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel9Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel9Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(7, 7, 7))
                    .addGroup(jPanel9Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)))
                .addGroup(jPanel9Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 69, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
        );

        jPanel10.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(7, 0, 0, 3));

        jButton4.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/icons/add_shopping_cart_40px.png"))); // NOI18N
        jPanel10.add(jButton4);

        jButton5.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/icons/up.png"))); // NOI18N
        jPanel10.add(jButton5);

        jButton6.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/icons/minus.png"))); // NOI18N
        jPanel10.add(jButton6);

        jButton7.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/icons/add_user.png"))); // NOI18N
        jPanel10.add(jButton7);

        jButton8.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/icons/delete.png"))); // NOI18N
        jPanel10.add(jButton8);

        jButton9.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/icons/edit_30px.png"))); // NOI18N
        jPanel10.add(jButton9);

        jButton10.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/icons/down.png"))); // NOI18N
        jPanel10.add(jButton10);

        cat_panel.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Category", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.CENTER, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 11), new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 51))); // NOI18N
        cat_panel.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(0, 1, 3, 5));

        jPanel5.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(1, 2, 2, 0));

        jButton14.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/icons/previous.png"))); // NOI18N
        jButton14.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        jButton14.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton14ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel5.add(jButton14);

        jButton15.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/icons/next_32.png"))); // NOI18N
        jButton15.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.LEFT);
        jButton15.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        jButton15.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton15ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel5.add(jButton15);

        jPanel6.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Groups", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.CENTER, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 11), new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 51))); // NOI18N
        jPanel6.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(1, 6, 3, 0));

        jButton22.setText("jButton22");
        jPanel6.add(jButton22);

        jButton23.setText("jButton23");
        jPanel6.add(jButton23);

        jButton24.setText("jButton23");
        jPanel6.add(jButton24);

        jButton25.setText("jButton22");
        jPanel6.add(jButton25);

        jButton26.setText("jButton23");
        jPanel6.add(jButton26);

        jButton27.setText("jButton22");
        jPanel6.add(jButton27);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jPanel10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 66, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(sch)
                    .addComponent(jPanel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 658, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jPanel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 124, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(cat_panel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGap(2, 2, 2))
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jPanel9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(cat_panel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jPanel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 52, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 0, 0)
                .addComponent(sch))
        );

        jTabbedPane1.addTab("ADD STOCK", jPanel2);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
        jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
        jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 1177, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 513, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jTabbedPane1.addTab("ADD ACCOUNTS", jPanel3);

        jPanel1.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(1, 6, 4, 0));

        jButton1.setText("Add New Stocks");
        jPanel1.add(jButton1);

        jButton2.setText("Add Category");
        jPanel1.add(jButton2);

        jButton3.setText("Modification Stock");
        jPanel1.add(jButton3);

        jButton11.setText("Add Groups");
        jPanel1.add(jButton11);
        jPanel1.add(jButton12);
        jPanel1.add(jButton13);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jTabbedPane1)
                .addContainerGap())
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 45, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(1, 1, 1)
                .addComponent(jTabbedPane1))
        );
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton15ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                         

    private void jButton14ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                         


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JPanel cat_panel;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton10;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton11;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton12;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton13;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton14;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton15;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton22;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton23;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton24;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton25;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton26;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton27;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton6;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton7;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton8;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton9;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel10;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel11;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel5;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel6;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel9;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTabbedPane jTabbedPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane sch;
    private org.edisoncor.gui.textField.TextFieldRectBackground textFieldRectBackground1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Next Pagination Button eventAction

```
private void jButton15ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

Previous Button Pagination event action

```
  private void jButton14ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }
```

Comment: 1) Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556). 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the DB. 3) Don't ignore exceptions! They inform us exactly what went wrong. Unless logging is implemented, at least call `Throwable.printStackTrace()` 4) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  ..

Comment: .. The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! Most IDEs have a keyboard shortcut specifically for formatting code. 5) See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)

Comment: could you please update your question with class file without `initComponent()` method

Comment: Theses button are print on Jpanel from database i have post cat_button() funcation reaming in my class is main method

Comment: Anyone provide me solution for this problem?

Comment: Anyone can help me please.!.

Comment: is there anyone java developer that help me???????????

Comment: Don't use the Back button to edit a post, it wipes out previous edits! Instead use the small [edit] link below left of the question. *"Theses button are print on Jpanel"* Who are you replying to? Tip: Add @CodeKadiya (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. *"is there anyone java developer that help me???????????"* I already gave you tips on what I need in order to offer further help. Add to that, **fix the broken `?` key.***

Comment: how i fix it? can you suggest me Next event action button code or previous event button cod?

Comment: okay you should move connection init  code blocks to the constructor then pass 1 parameter to get  current page and append the sql query with limit and offset as well as initialized  `JFlowPanel` as a Global Variable then remove all element before adding child element then iterate the result set as you want then add the component to `JFlowPanel`  after that you can use your `cat_buttons(pagenum);` on your next and previous button, if you update question with your class I'll add Answer, Thanks

Comment: okey i am update own class please add answer.

Comment: @Code Kadiya please add Answer i have update own class please.

Comment: @Code KadiyaDear Respected Please post Answer.

Comment: *Anyone can help me please* - no because: 1) you haven't asked a proper question. You haven't defined what the "Previous/Next" buttons should do. Should you scroll one button at a time? Should you scroll all the components in the scroll pane at once 2) you haven't posted an [mre]. Your question is about scrolling a group of button on a panel. The database is irrelevant to your problem. The code you posted is of no use to us. What you need to do is create a loop to add buttons to a panel. Then you add your "Previous/Next" buttons. Then you write the ActionListener code for the two buttons..

Comment: Once you get that basic logic working, then you change the code to dynamically generate the buttons from a database.

Comment: (1-) Also, quit using multiple ids to ask the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60695568/131872. The standard answer you will get in the forum is to do the work yourself. You have been given suggestion on how to 1) break down the solution into individual steps. 2) ask a better question 3) post proper code. Until these steps are followed you will NOT get specific help.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the bellow solution and update it as you required

```
import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;
import static java.awt.Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

/**
 *
 * @author ultronhouse11
 */
public class mainPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    /**
     * Creates new form mainPanel
     */
    private JButton btnCategory;
    final int col = 5;
    final int rows = 2;

    private Connection con;
    private int pageIndex = 1;

    public mainPanel() {
        initComponents();
        // open mysql connectivity 
        openConnection();
        // load first page initialy
        loadPage(pageIndex);
    }

    private void openConnection(){
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shopingmoll", "root", "qwer9900");
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void loadPage(int page) {
        this.pageIndex = page;
        try {
            // Customize page size here
            int pageSize = 10;

            String sl = "SELECT * FROM `item_types` LIMIT ? OFFSET ?";
            PreparedStatement pst = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sl);
            pst.setInt(0, pageSize);
            pst.setInt(1, pageSize * page);
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

            // remove all child elements 
            cat_panel.removeAll();

             while (rs.next()) {

                String a1 = rs.getString("name");
                String a2 = rs.getString("id");
                JButton btn = new JButton();


                btn.setText("<html><body> <h3>" + a1 + "</h3><br> <b></body></html> ");
                btn.setVerticalAlignment((int) CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
                btn.applyComponentOrientation(getComponentOrientation());
                btn.setFocusPainted(false);
                btn.setFocusable(false);
                btn.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);
                btn.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(110, 90));
                btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(90, 80));
                btn.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(110, 90));

                btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        System.out.println(a1+":"+a2);
                    }
                });

                //String a2 = rs.getString(2);
                ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("src/posresturent/cat.jpg");
                // btn.setIcon(img);

                btn.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                btn.setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
                btn.setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.BOTTOM);
                cat_panel.add(btn,"center");

                cat_panel.repaint();
                cat_panel.revalidate();
             }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jTabbedPane1 = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        sch = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jPanel9 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel11 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        textFieldRectBackground1 = new org.edisoncor.gui.textField.TextFieldRectBackground();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel10 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton6 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton7 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton8 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton9 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton10 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        cat_panel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel5 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButton14 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton15 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jPanel6 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButton22 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton23 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton24 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton25 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton26 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton27 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton11 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton12 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton13 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        sch.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Items", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.CENTER, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION));

        jPanel11.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(1, 0));

        textFieldRectBackground1.setDescripcion("Enter Barcode ...");
        textFieldRectBackground1.setFocusCycleRoot(true);
        jPanel11.add(textFieldRectBackground1);

        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "#SrNo", "Product", "Unit", "Rate"
            }
        ));
        jTable1.setRowHeight(35);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("Total ");

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("Tax");

        jTextField1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jTextField1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.RIGHT);
        jTextField1.setText("0.00");

        jTextField2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jTextField2.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.RIGHT);
        jTextField2.setText("0.00");

        jTextField3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 1, 45)); // NOI18N
        jTextField3.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 51));
        jTextField3.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.CENTER);
        jTextField3.setText(" Rs  0.00");

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setText("<html> Grand <br><br> Total");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel9Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel9);
        jPanel9.setLayout(jPanel9Layout);
        jPanel9Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel9Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel11, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(jPanel9Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel9Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(35, 35, 35)
                .addGroup(jPanel9Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 230, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING))
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 309, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        );
        jPanel9Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel9Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel9Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel11, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 33, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(1, 1, 1)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel9Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel9Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(7, 7, 7))
                    .addGroup(jPanel9Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)))
                .addGroup(jPanel9Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 69, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
        );

        jPanel10.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(7, 0, 0, 3));

        jButton4.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/icons/add_shopping_cart_40px.png"))); // NOI18N
        jPanel10.add(jButton4);

        jButton5.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/icons/up.png"))); // NOI18N
        jPanel10.add(jButton5);

        jButton6.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/icons/minus.png"))); // NOI18N
        jPanel10.add(jButton6);

        jButton7.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/icons/add_user.png"))); // NOI18N
        jPanel10.add(jButton7);

        jButton8.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/icons/delete.png"))); // NOI18N
        jPanel10.add(jButton8);

        jButton9.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/icons/edit_30px.png"))); // NOI18N
        jPanel10.add(jButton9);

        jButton10.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/icons/down.png"))); // NOI18N
        jPanel10.add(jButton10);

        cat_panel.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Category", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.CENTER, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 11), new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 51))); // NOI18N
        cat_panel.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(0, 1, 3, 5));

        jPanel5.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(1, 2, 2, 0));

        jButton14.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/icons/previous.png"))); // NOI18N
        jButton14.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        jButton14.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton14ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel5.add(jButton14);

        jButton15.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/icons/next_32.png"))); // NOI18N
        jButton15.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.LEFT);
        jButton15.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        jButton15.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton15ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel5.add(jButton15);

        jPanel6.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Groups", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.CENTER, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 11), new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 51))); // NOI18N
        jPanel6.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(1, 6, 3, 0));

        jButton22.setText("jButton22");
        jPanel6.add(jButton22);

        jButton23.setText("jButton23");
        jPanel6.add(jButton23);

        jButton24.setText("jButton23");
        jPanel6.add(jButton24);

        jButton25.setText("jButton22");
        jPanel6.add(jButton25);

        jButton26.setText("jButton23");
        jPanel6.add(jButton26);

        jButton27.setText("jButton22");
        jPanel6.add(jButton27);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jPanel10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 66, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(sch)
                    .addComponent(jPanel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 658, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jPanel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 124, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(cat_panel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGap(2, 2, 2))
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jPanel9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(cat_panel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jPanel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 52, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 0, 0)
                .addComponent(sch))
        );

        jTabbedPane1.addTab("ADD STOCK", jPanel2);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
        jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
        jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 1177, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 513, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jTabbedPane1.addTab("ADD ACCOUNTS", jPanel3);

        jPanel1.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(1, 6, 4, 0));

        jButton1.setText("Add New Stocks");
        jPanel1.add(jButton1);

        jButton2.setText("Add Category");
        jPanel1.add(jButton2);

        jButton3.setText("Modification Stock");
        jPanel1.add(jButton3);

        jButton11.setText("Add Groups");
        jPanel1.add(jButton11);
        jPanel1.add(jButton12);
        jPanel1.add(jButton13);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jTabbedPane1)
                .addContainerGap())
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 45, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(1, 1, 1)
                .addComponent(jTabbedPane1))
        );
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton15ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // next button
        loadPage(pageIndex+1);
    }                                         

    private void jButton14ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // previous button
        loadPage(pageIndex-1);
    }                                         


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JPanel cat_panel;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton10;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton11;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton12;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton13;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton14;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton15;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton22;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton23;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton24;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton25;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton26;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton27;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton6;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton7;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton8;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton9;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel10;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel11;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel5;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel6;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel9;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTabbedPane jTabbedPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane sch;
    private org.edisoncor.gui.textField.TextFieldRectBackground textFieldRectBackground1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

> Previous Button Event Code when press button console error

```
  loadPage(pageIndex + 1);
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(pageIndex - 1));
```

> Previous Button after press console error.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-4' at line 1
0
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at 
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at
```

Comment: Thanks for your cooperation Previous/Next buttons when i press nothing any chnage in cat_panel still same button when page load.

Comment: can you upload your code to github then mention the link

Comment: console error is some  java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (0 < 1 ).
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)

Comment: sir here i have upload source code on github please view it @Code Kadiya        https://github.com/ultrasol/POS_Resturant

Comment: source code on github and this is the link kindly check it, https://github.com/ultrasol/POS_Resturant